# Sorting Filter values asc/desc on Tibco Spotfire

Tags: tibco, spotfire

How do i sort the values of a filter asc/desc in Tibco spotfire? 
I tried changing the MySQL query with ORDER BY for that specific column but that doesn't help?

Answer (score 0):

You said "sort the values of a *filter*" -- do you mean you want to control the order of items in the filter panel? To do so, right click anywhere in the filter panel and choose Organize Filters. There you can use the Move Up/Move Down buttons to arrange to your preference.

If instead you want to sort a Table visualization (a basic grid), you can just click on a column header for sorting. One click sorts ascending, another click sorts descending, and a third click returns the column to the original sort order before you started clicking.

You can use the Shift key to sort multiple columns. Sort your first column how you want it, then hold down the Shift key and click another column header to sort it, and so on.

You can also right-click the visualization and open the Properties dialog. There's a Sorting option where you can choose how to sort up to three columns.

I hope this was helpful.

Comment: Nope. I have a Date Column Filter and within that filter, by default, the dates are sorted Asc order but i wanted them to show up in desc order(latest date values to top the filter) Also this solution doesn't help https://tibbr.tibcommunity.com/tibbr/#!/messages/93384

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. It seems like a good feature to include on the Filtering Scheme Properties form.