# Make Spotfire ignore empty values in the categories of charts and show a visualization without "spaces" between the bars

Tags: data-visualization, spotfire

I have a group of trellis graphs on some data, in there you can see a numeric variable on the Y axis and a series of cell dishes on the X axis. Not all the numeric values are present on all the series of cells. Because of this the visualization results in a graph with empty spaces:

[image]

This is OK most of the time but the thing is I would like to avoid the "empty spaces, only in these graph series, that you can see between the bars. I would like to see showing only the pattern of the cell dishes where I have data.

Trying to do so I tried creating a calculated column to use it as a ordering index (https://docs.tibco.com/pub/sfire-bauthor/7.9.0/doc/html/en-US/GUID-8CAA18D0-CF28-4707-9945-041BDFD99E99.html) ([Sorting Filter values asc/desc on Tibco Spotfire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24807065/sorting-filter-values-asc-desc-on-tibco-spotfire)), after that "Limit data by expression" using a "[MyColumn] is not null" on it (https://community.tibco.com/questions/can-i-automatically-make-spotfire-ignore-empty-values-categories-charts) ([How to show the top 10 column values in Spotfire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29787828/how-to-show-the-top-10-column-values-in-spotfire)) with no luck and I tried also (https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/6.5.1/doc/html/ncfe/ncfe_details_on_custom_expression.htm) create a custom expression, which I think it would be a good solution because I understand it will only affect these graphs and not the complete set of visualizations but no, I don't reach the point to change it. Last that it should work but it doesn't is to "Show/Hide Items" under a Boolean expression that it would include that "[Axis.Value] is not NULL" and "Apply individually for each trellis panel" of the numeric column which sound terrific but... nope, it didn't work either...

Any help would be appreciated, now I will select one by one on individual graphs extracting them and plotting them in other place but this is not very useful as a "large scale" solution. I am sure there is a way to insert a proper expression to avoid the null values of the cross of both variables, the numeric and the cell dishes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is because you are trellising data, not the axis. you won't be able to filter out values on the x axis; it's simply not how trellis works.

using multiple visualizations is the solution, but I assume you've got *n* sets of categories that you want to separate out without creating a ton of charts on the page and perhaps you can't guarantee the number of categories or their names, so you want to build a flexible solution.

please check out an answer I just wrote [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46792574/4419423) which illustrates how to use a document property and a property control to limit a visualization. your property control can be linked to automatically and dynamically display unique values in your "category" column (the one you are trellising by). maybe this can be a solution for you?

Comment: Good catch on the trellis. I missed that.

Comment: Yep, that is working!, you were right about the trellis and the individual visualizations. Now I will create a "drop-down lists area" on the top of the dashboard so the users can select from four to six (or something like that) and see the graphs without the spaces. Many thanks niko!