# Match two trellis pages between two different graphs

Tags: data-visualization, spotfire

I want to have on the same page a pie chart and a bar chart, with trellis pages.
They both have 5 columns as trellis, so 5 different pages that you can visualize by scrolling down.

However, I would like to display the same pages at the same time for both graphs. For instance, let's imagine I'm on the pie chart, I scroll down one page - and so my pie chart is on page2 - I want my bar chart to automatically go to page 2 as well

I tried to use markings but although it links a bit the two graphs, it doesn't change the trellis pages automatically

Does anyone know how to do this ?

Comment: You are trying to fit 10 visualizations on a single page?

Comment: Yes but thanks to the trellis visualization I only have two visualizations at the same time (the rest is obtained by scrolling down with the mouse on the graph). I just want my two graphs (pie chart and bar chart) to be synchronized on the same column (for instance if with the pie chart I'm on the trellis page for column 2, I want to be on the trellis page for column 2 as well for the bar chart)

Comment: I understand and unfortunately that is not possible using the native trellis feature. I can't think of a custom way to do this either, but I'm certain it would be quite cumbersome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as @scsimon mentions, there's no native feature (nor API method, AFAIK) for this using a trellis. however, you can create a Property Control (I'd use a dropdown) in a Text Area, then use the same Document Property to your chart in a Limit By expression.

little more detail, assuming a data table like this:

```
A   B   CATEGORY
1   2   red
3   4   red
5   6   green
7   8   green
9   10  blue
11  12  blue
```

1. add a **Text Area** to the page and edit its contents
2. add a **Property Control**
3. click **New** to create a **Document Property**, give it a type String and a name `category`
4. change *Set property value through* to **Unique values in column** and choose the "category" column and click **OK**
5. save the **Text Area** contents
6. in your **Pie Chart**'s Properties dialog, go to the **Data** page and look for *Limit data using expression*. click **Edit**
7. set the expression to: `[CATEGORY] = "${category}"` (don't forget the quotes or the Document Property won't be treated as a string and you'll get an error)
8. repeat steps 6 & 7 for your other chart

Comment: Welcome back Niko 

Answer (score 3):

As @scsimon mentioned in the comments, it seems to be impossible. I found a way to have a similar representation though without using trellis visualization, by using text arena

I created a list box that contains the 5 columns I want to visualize, and then I select this list box as the vertical axis variable of the bar chart and the sector size of the pie chart

Then, by clicking on my list box, I can have a synchronized Pie chart and Bar chart (a bit different from what I expected but it also has some advantages like a multiple scale since a new graph is generated independently of the other variables)

Comment: Neat idea. I'll have to try this